# ActionBar menu not works in ActionMode

Tags: android

I am newbie to Android Development, I am looking to get an one more menu on ActionMode, that is along with cut,copy,selectAll. I want to add "mark" to this menu.

So I added an item in main.xml below is the following code of it.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.fn.MainActivity" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings1"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:onClick="onContextualMenuItemClicked"
    android:title="Mark"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>  

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

This was tested and works fine in most of the phones, but in few phones it long pressing on texts, it shows the message

`unfortunately, app has stopped`

there is no other process and my app was closed suddenly.

I am not sure why? can someone assist me here?

If I remove this following line from that item, it will works.

```
    android:onClick="onContextualMenuItemClicked"
```

but I am triggering that onclick in Activity,

```
public void onContextualMenuItemClicked(MenuItem item) {
    /*switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.mark:
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:doMouseUp();");             
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("default");
            break;
    }
    if (mActionMode != null) {
        mActionMode.finish();
    }*/
}
```

### Update

```
@Override
public void onActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode) {
    if (mActionMode == null) {
        mActionMode = mode;
        Menu menu = mode.getMenu();
        menu.clear();
        mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    }
    super.onActionModeStarted(mode);
}
```

Comment: Why do you have that onclick? Its not going to work as you you think.

Comment: It works in LG, Lenovo phones, but not in Coolpad dazen mobile

Comment: Post the the method you use to open the action mode.

Comment: Updated my question, pls take a look

Comment: I meant the way how you call the action mode? Is it from a list view item long click? You need to post that particular code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are extending the MainActivity with `ActionBarActivity`. This is supports only after the Android KitKat. In version 5 and later it doesn't make problem.

You need to extend the MainActivity with  Activity, then it will works for you.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
```

Then, You need to have separate xml file (myMenu.xml) under /res/menu in your project structure.

myMenu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.fn.MainActivity" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/mark"       
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:onClick="onContextualMenuItemClicked"
        android:title="Mark">
    </item>

</menu>
```

Copy this method and change as per your need and replace in Activity.

```
@Override
public void onActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode) {
    if (mActionMode == null) {
        mActionMode = mode;
        Menu menu = mode.getMenu();
        menu.clear();
        mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(myMenu, menu);
    }
    super.onActionModeStarted(mode);
}
```

That's all, hope now it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mary

Comment: maybe AppCompatActivity is better alter. use that instead

Comment: I have tried to do exactly the same but I'm getting android.view.InflateException: Couldn't resolve menu item onClick handler onContextualMenuItemClicked in class android.app.ContextImpl

Answer (score 0):

You can try something dynamic!!
Override this method

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    CreateMenu(menu);

    return true;
}
```

Make this Method

```
private void CreateMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuItem mnu1 = menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Delete");
        {
            //mnu1.setIcon(R..ic_menu_delete);
            //R.drawable.ic_menu_delete
            mnu1.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
        }
        MenuItem mnu2 = menu.add(0, 1, 1, "Edit");
        {
            //mnu2.setIcon();
            mnu2.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
        }


    }

}
```

And for onClick override this

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return MenuChoice(item);
}
```

and create this method

```
private boolean MenuChoice(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case 0:
            //your method here

            return true;
        case 1:
            //your method here
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

My code creates 2 options

Comment: Feel free to ask for any doubts

Comment: Daksh Agrawal, Thanks for your answer. I tried this.Its not available, I am long pressing texts in webview in my app...